# What did Jon mean?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Towards the end of the final episode of *Game of Thrones* Jon is talking with the remaining Starks and says to Bran "I'm sorry I wasn't there for you" but what does he mean?
The only time Jon could have done anything to protect Bran was the 'Hold the door' moment and being pushed out if the tower window by Jaime so what was he referencing?

Comment: And the whole time he was wandering around the wilderness? And the part where Winterfell got sacked?

Comment: It's a dupe!!! Should have asked last night!!!